# NSData to NSMutableArray of NSData by fixed length

Tags: objective-c, nsdata

I am trying to get NSMutableArray from NSData by 16 bytes, but failing to do so. Maybe anyone could point me in the right direction.

Example:
input: `<c4ebc39d edf81fe6 09e0a41a 34b4d20d c4ebc39d edf81fe6 09e0a41a 34b4d20d>`

output: `<c4ebc39d edf81fe6 09e0a41a 34b4d20d> <c4ebc39d edf81fe6 09e0a41a 34b4d20d>`

I am trying like this:

```
NSMutableArray *blocks = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i <= [data length]; i=i+16) {
    unsigned char *byte = NULL;
    [data getBytes:byte range:NSMakeRange(i, 16)];
    NSData *temp = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:byte length:sizeof(byte)];
    [blocks addObject:temp];
}
```

For some reason this throws me exc_bad_access.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[data getBytes:byte range:NSMakeRange(i, 16)];
```

copies the data into the memory pointed to by `byte`, it does not allocate memory. Copying the data crashes because `byte  == NULL` does not point to valid memory. Replacing

```
unsigned char *byte = NULL;
```

by

```
unsigned char byte[16];
```

should solve the problem. But note that

```
NSData *temp = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 16)];
```

is even easier and does not require the byte buffer at all.

Note also that the for loop

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i <= [data length]; i=i+16)
```

should be changed to

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i <= [data length] - 16; i=i+16)
```

to avoid access to the `data` object beyond its bounds.

You loop would then look like this:

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i <= [data length] - 16; i = i + 16) {
    NSData *temp = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 16)];
    [blocks addObject:temp];
}
```

Comment: Wow.. Thank you for great explanation and great answer. I have definetly learned a few things from it. Thank you once more.